# GKE and multiple VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a GKE autopilot cluster where I deployed a workload that needs to connect to two SQL databases via two different on-premise VPNs. The network is on another project and it is a shared VPC.

The GKE configuration is this:

- private cluster
- subnet control plane 172.20.0.0/28, pods 172.18.0.0/16, services 172.19.0.0/16
- dataplane v2 enabled

The two VPNs have one tunnel each (no HA) and use the IkeV1 version.
I connected the VPNs to two different subnets from those of the pods and services, respectively 172.21.0.16/29 and 172.21.0.24/29.
I updated the GKE peer connection to import the new routes that I actually see under "exported routes".

If I create a VM within the two subnets I can connect correctly to the databases but not from the pod.

Is what I'm doing correct, that is, connecting the VPNs to subnets different from those of the cluster?
Or would it be more correct to connect them to network of the cluster?

I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59207115/egress-traffic-from-gke-pod-through-vpn) solution but it doesn't work because I'm on a GKE Autopilot.
Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66949467/gke-vpn-to-on-premise-database) doesn't work because I can't delete the ip-masq-agent pods.

**SOLUTION**: I've resolved by changing type of VPN from Classic to HA with one tunnel.
This enabled the dynamic routes that, like I've done with Classic vpn, are imported in gke cluster peer connection.
From pods I tried to connect the Sql database and all works perfectly.

Comment: Can you check the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters) which has different kind of scenarios related to subnets and IP address assignments between pods,nodes and clusters.